# Page / Slice containing unknown instances in spring's pagination and slicing over mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, pagination, slice

When trying to use spring's pagination or slicing to iterate a very large mongodb collection, the program runs ok but at certain point the next page / slice is empty and in debug there is the message of "Page / Slice containing unknown instances".

Here is the code sample:

```
do {
  Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageNumber, PAGE_SIZE, sort);
  nextPage = catsRepository.findByTypeAndIdGreaterThan("street cat", lastId, 
          pageable);
  dbRecords = nextPage.getContent();
   if (dbRecords.size() > 0) {
       lastId = new ObjectId( doSomthing());
       pageNumber++; 

    }
 } while (nextPage.hasNext());
```

Also, when using different page size, it seems like the location of the problem is different:

After running with slice of size 1, problem at slice 133

After running with slice of size 2, problem at slice  98

After running with slice of size 3, problem at slice 76

Is there a malformed document in the DB that can cause this?

During the iteration I calculate the expected number of slices / pages and the loops stops before it reaches that number.

what can cause such a thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Normally it happens when you are requesting a pageNumber "out of bounds". 
Suppose you have 10 registers in db that you want and you define a `PAGE_SIZE=10`, so you have only one page and its index is 0, that means if you request for `pageNumber=1`, you will get containing unknown instances problem.

Summarizing, try for `pageNumber=0`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using BOTH sorting by _id AND increasing the requested page number at the same time.

Once I keep on requesting page number 0 all the time, the problem is over.

Comment: Do you know why spring has this behaviour ?

Comment: This happens if you modify documents in that way that searched properties are modified. For example search for documents with an id greater than value x. Then modify the id of the documents that were returned by the query so that their id does not match the following query. If you have a page size of 5 and a total of 10 documents that match the query the first query would find 5 documents an their id is modified. The next query with page 2 would find nothing cause their are only 5 documents left with a matching id.